# Laravel command exec output

Tags: php, laravel, bash, shell, laravel-artisan

I am trying to make artisan command which would execute a non-ending script (more precisely it is a gulp watch command). Is it possible to output something to console in real time and not waiting for script to end?

```
exec($basedir . "test.sh", $output);

foreach ($output as $item) {
    $this->info($item);
}
```

`test.sh` looks like this (shortened for brevity):

```
echo "something"
echo "something else"

gulp watch
```

Since command doesn't actually end, I can't retrieve two echos running inside it. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved it by doing the following:

```
while (@ ob_end_flush()) ; // end all output buffers if any

// this section streams output to terminal 
$proc = popen($basedir . "test.sh", 'r');
while (!feof($proc)) {
    $this->info(fread($proc, 4096));
    @ flush();
}
```